# Can´t use adMob api since I updated to API 19

Tags: android, google-play, admob

Alright, If I include the .jar of the adMob sdk, it will conflict with the google play services API and the app wont compile because of the following error:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

If I dont include the adMob .jar on the exports, it will crash on runtime because the app couldnt find the classes required for the ad and it displays this message on my layout file:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView
```

What now? It broke after I updated to API 19.
Im using the google play services API revision 13 and version 6.4.1 of the adMob .jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did. Remove the AdMob.jar. Remove all your imports relating to AdMob stuff. Then follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration) to update your code, because the API has changed somewhat.

Comment: Right on the spot. Also had to add the previous suggestion and update the adActivity tag on the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need this line in your manifest file as direct element of application tag:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I assume I must also add a integer to the values files. What number I put for the google_play_services_version?

Comment: There is nothing on it, because the project wont compile.