# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity;

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm trying to use google play services in my app.

i have referenced the library, google play serves, in both my app and BaseGameUtils and I have Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdActivity; "

usually what that means is that you have two .jar files that have the same class name. My only problem is I don't know which jar files have the same classes. Also, I do not have google-play-services as a jar in my libs folder nor have i added it as an external jar in the build path menu. So all i have are two dependencies google-play-servies, and BaseGameUtils, which also uses google-play-servies as a library. So can someone tell me what this issue even means, cause i've tried everything..

here's my research to show i've tried to help myself..

[Can´t use adMob api since I updated to API 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050455/can%C2%B4t-use-admob-api-since-i-updated-to-api-19)

[Android Build fail - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/api/client/escape/CharEscapers;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437796/android-build-fail-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-already-added-lcom-goo)

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

[adMob.jar library and google play service.jar not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723898/admob-jar-library-and-google-play-service-jar-not-working-together)

Answer (score 0):

> So all i have are two dependencies google-play-servies, and BaseGameUtils, which also uses google-play-servies as a library

Are you saying that you are referencing Google Play Services in both BaseGameUtils and your project ?

In BaseGameUtils reference Google Play Services.

In your project reference BaseGameUtils.

Then check to ensure you have got your advertising set up correctly (admobs is now in google play services , no longer a separate jar):

[Multiple dex files define - Deleting extra jar file still not working. What should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767977/multiple-dex-files-define-deleting-extra-jar-file-still-not-working-what-shou/24800861#24800861)